# How to customize Google play services to decrease jar size?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I wonder if there is a way to customize `google-play-services.jar`.

[Google play services version 6.1](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html#)

I found that new version has 24K methods that makes my application out of Max method count (~65K) and therefore I can't create APK file (or DEX).

In the past I saw on some site that you can configure `google-play-services.jar` by enable/disable
 unused features.

My old jar weight is 7K (instead 19K) and I can't jump to 24K, too expansive.

Any suggestions please?

**[EDIT]**

I found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036617/proguard-google-play-services-jar)** question where `@Eric Lafortune` suggests to use Proguard

Comment: Have you tried turning on ProGuard?

Comment: @Squeazer Yes I thought to use proGuard but I remember on site I was able to check/uncheck flags with features and download customized jar. Today can't find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping in mind that:

- Using Proguard is always recommended
- [MultiDex](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/JW9x4pcB1rj), despite adding overhead at runtime, is the only viable solution **when you are really using all of those methods** (which is rarely the case!)

If you are using Gradle and just want to exclude automatically the parts of Play Services that you don't use, this is the easiest, fastest, and most efficient way: https://gist.github.com/Takhion/10a37046b9e6d259bb31.

Just add it as suggested and comment the `exclude` on the parts that you **need**!

Sooo useful for debug builds where you **don't** want to go through Proguard each time ;)

Comment: @fessy add `strip_play_services.gradle` in the same folder where you have your app's `build.gradle` and inside that add `apply from: 'strip_play_services.gradle'` (I do it after the various plugins). If you use Proguard, add the line in the gist to your `proguard-rules.txt` and you're set! Now rebuild and enjoy :)

Comment: @Takhion is this possible to exclude the classes from google play services library project? because i am using eclipse not Android studio.

Comment: @Amarnath the script relies on Gradle. You can technically strip the packages manually but that's a huge pain... If you can, you should switch to Gradle / Android Studio!

Answer (score 14):

Ideally you should use ProGurad, however you can follow these two steps:

**Step 1: Remove unused classes from jar file**

Open the **google-play-services.jar** in the library project with a zip file manager such as Winrar or 7zip. You will find many folder such as `maps, games`, just delete the ones you don't need. Make sure you keep `common, dynamic, internal` .

**Step 2: Remove unused resource from res folder**

Most of the resources in the google-play-services_lib\res folder might be of no use so you can remove it. These include `values-af, values-am,` .... what you need to keep is color, `drawable, drawable-hdpi` and `values` folder.

Refresh and build the **google-play-services_lib** project and your project. Your apk size should be decreased.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This saved me from the [65k method issue](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  I was tearing my hair out with the 65k method issue..  This is fantastic.

Comment: can you let me know which folder I can delete I only need gcm feature I'm not sure which one I can delete (

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio You can use individual library from google play service such as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

complete list is available here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Some APIs do not have a separate library; include them by including the base library

Answer (score 0):

Do you target android 2.3 or not ?

If not, use MultiDex Support Library.

From here : [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/JW9x4pcB1rj).

---

MultiDex Support Library

So your application has grown too large: you're over the Dex limit. Maybe you've taken advantage of some of the ridiculously useful libraries out there that could stand to lose some weight (Google Play Services, I'm looking at you). You've had to resort to limiting the functionality of your app or doing crazy hacks to work around the limit. No more: welcome MultiDexApplication!

MultiDexApplication, part of a simple android-support-multidex.jar found in `sdk\extras\android\support\multidex\library\libs`, gives you MultiDex support on all API 4+ devices (well, until v21, where you get this natively) by having your Application extend MultiDexApplication or call MultiDex.install(context) in your application's attachBaseContext. That's it. Seriously.

Note: you should really, really Proguard before going down the Multidex rabbit hole.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)